# How do I WebView a pdf link on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm trying to display a pdf file from the web (from a link) onto my Flutter application as a WebView. However, my screen in blank. Any other websites that is not pdf work fine, but whenever I put a pdf link in, it just displays nothing.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
  ),
  body: const WebView(
    initialUrl: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView only works fine with very small pdf files and cause issues with slightly larger files. To view pdf files, use other package like:
flutter_pdfview, advance_pdf_viewer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
  ),
  body: const WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  ),
);
```

or this

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
```