# Flutter pdf view with remote url

Tags: flutter

I need to show in app pdf view. For this I was able to do so with pdf packages but it resulted in app size getting larger. [How do I WebView a pdf link on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769673/how-do-i-webview-a-pdf-link-on-flutter) This answer helped too but now the webview package has WebViewWidget(controller: controller), and I cannot load the pdf with webview. Does anyone have a solution for this? I could lower the package version but if there is any solution with WebViewWidget then that would be good too. Thank you in advance.